# Express in terms of y, $-\varepsilon x+c_0 = \log y +\alpha\left[\frac{1}{1+\beta y}+\log\left(\frac{\beta y}{1+\beta y}\right)\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Can this function be expressed in terms of $y$?

$$-\varepsilon x+c_0 = \log y +\alpha\left[\frac{1}{1+\beta y}+\log\left(\frac{\beta y}{1+\beta y}\right)\right]$$

I'm wondering if this is possible by transforming it into some expression where the Lambert W function can be used to invert it?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

$$x=ye^y \Longleftrightarrow y = W(x)$$

I've tried but not managed as of yet, do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may write the expression as follows:

$-ԑx =-ln(e^{ C_O}) + ln y+ln( e^{\frac{α}{1+βy}})+ln{(\frac{βy}{1+βy})^{α}} $

$x=\frac{-ln\frac{{(\frac{βy}{1+βy})^{α}}.y.( e^{\frac{α}{1+βy}})}{e^{C_O}}}{ԑ}$

Comment: Thanks for this! So do you have any idea how to invert this?

Comment: May be this idea works;$ \frac{{(\frac{βy}{1+βy})^{α}}.y.( e^{\frac{α}{1+βy}})}{e^{C_O}}=.( e^{\frac{α}{1+βy}})^{'}$ ; then we find $y=f(α,β,C_O)$ which gives y(real and complex depending on negative or positive,α,β, C_O) independent from x; and $y=f(x)$ which is exponential and can be real or complex depending on ԑ.